# Using PrimeNG DataTables

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

Trying to setup DataTable from [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable). I get the response back from the API like this

`[{"firstName":"Mop","lastName":"Top","eId":"aaa123","tech":"AWS"},{"firstName":"Hey","lastName":"Arnold","eId":"hfg456","tech":"AWS"},{"firstName":"Hom","lastName":"Mom","eId":"abf654","tech":"AWS"}]`

It seems I might be using `ngFor` wrong because it does not load the array to the table ? There is no error in the console so I'm not sure exactly I'm doing wrong.

[Link to my code](https://github.com/BillyCharter87/Tech-O-Dex-UI/blob/891d493f7b0b7e159eece554c71f8955384e23ac/src/app/table/table.component.html#L9-L14)

Yes I know Datatable is deprecated but I could not get `TableModule` to import :(

Comment: Why would you in a world use *ngFor in column definition?

Comment: You better check PrimeNG docs on how to use tables.

Comment: @Antoniossss the documentation for datatables shows doing that I believe?

Comment: No, example in docs does not do *ngFor N times in colums section

Comment: You do know that `*ngFor` is a loop construct right ??

Comment: What is your `cols` variable? If you use `*ngFor`, you should have only one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only use *ngFor with p-columns if you want your table's columns to be dynamic. Judging by your code, your columns are not defined in the typescript at all, therefore they should be defined statically in your html:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="tech">
  <p-column field="firstName" header="First Name"></p-column>
  <p-column field="lastName" header="Last Name"></p-column>
  <p-column field="eId" header="E Id"></p-column>
  <p-column field="tech" header="Tech"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

In [PrimeNG's documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable), this information is under the first "Source" tab, right under "Basic".